# Where are apps from the Pi Store stored?

Tags: raspbian, pi-store

I have installed a few apps from the Pi Store, and opening the Pi Store to access those apps isn't ideal. Where is the actual location of the apps I got from the Pi Store so I could access them directly?

Comment: I'm not really sure but i would look under the following path: /home/pi/....

Comment: There is a folder for Indiecity (the engine that runs Pi Store), but there's only program files that run Pi Store.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're at `/usr/local/bin/indiecity/InstalledApps`